# Mysql table collation differs from database collation on Windows

Tags: mysql

I have always ran mysql on Linux, but last week I installed mysql on my Windows 10 laptop itself.
I have set the default characterset and collation as follows:

```
[mysqld]

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

This seems to work in that, when I create a database without specifying those, the character-set and collation of the database seem to be right.

However, when I import any SQL to that database all tables suddenly have collation "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci".
Even though that would be fine to me (since that's a good collation to use), people I work with cannot work with that collation.

**The process**
I create a mysqldump from commandline on my Linux vm. The database runs on my Linux vm as well.
The current characterset is "utf8" with collation "utf8_general_ci".
The dump file itself does not seem to contain collation information.

I then import that file to mysql (which runs on my Windows installation) via my Linux commandline (connecting to 10.10.10.1).

So: why does mysql use that collation, while I have specified otherwise?

Comment: How do you do the "SQL import"? Does the import file include collation definitions?

Comment: Good question. The import file does not seem to contain collation definitions. I added my process in my post now.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` is the [default collation][1] for `utf8mb4`-charset. When you load the SQL-file and do not specify the collation, the default collation will be used. Take a look at the variables by issuing a command:

```
mysql> show variables like '%collation%';
```

You can change the value for the `default_collation_for_utf8mb4` variable or use:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

to define the collation for the connection.

Comment: I think you are right (I will accept this as the answer as soon as I have it working). However putting `default_collation_for_utf8mb4=utf8mb4_general_ci` in my.ini won't let me startup mysql anymore. So how do I set this variable globally?

I found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_collation_for_utf8mb4, but it's not clear to me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable in the command tool, but for some reason not in my.ini (this is a bug):

```
mysql> SET default_collation_for_utf8mb4=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

And use this command to check if it's ok:

```
mysql> show variables like '%collation%';

+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value              |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection          | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database            | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server              | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| default_collation_for_utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Also, just to be sure:
[I go to phpmyadmin, select each database, click on operations and check both checkmarks at collation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atr5k.png)

I think this is new in phpmyadmin 5.